# How to upgrade softwares from currently installed LAMP on a 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 LTS system? Please provide me the step-by-step instructions

Tags: server, apache2, php, mysql, lamp

Someone had installed LAMP on my machine almost two(2) years back. I got this machine since last six(6) months. The LAMP is working fine for all of the PHP project work I do. But the issue is all the softwares from this LAMP package have not been updated since very long. For your information I'm putting below the details of versions of these softwares which are currently installed on my machine:
**PHP :**

```
PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.13 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Jul  7 2014 18:54:55) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

**Apache web server :**

```
/usr/sbin/apachectl: 87: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jul 22 2014 14:35:25
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:30
Server loaded:  APR 1.4.6, APR-Util 1.3.12
Compiled using: APR 1.4.6, APR-Util 1.3.12
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     Prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/apache2"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/lib/apache2/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/apache2.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_LOCKFILE="/var/run/apache2/accept.lock"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="apache2.conf"
```

**MySQL :**

```
5.5.38-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
```

I want to upgrade the above softwares to following verions :

**PHP 5.5.17

Apache httpd 2.4.10

MySQL 5.6.20**

Can someone please provide me the easiest way by means of in details step-by-step instructions for upgrading and making the whole LAMP package workable?

It would be of great help to me as well as all other members from Ubuntu community who want to upgrade the LAMP softwares they are currently using.

Thanks for spending some of your valuable time in understanding my issue. Waiting for your precious replies.

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: @Parto:I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit OS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without wandering into the unknown territory of compiling packages yourself, the best solution here is to find and add a PPA (which is a "personal" repository) which hosts these packages.

Luckily for you, there are PPAs for all your packages, maintained by debian packagers / maintainers:

- PHP 5.5: https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php5 (ppa:ondrej/php5)
- Apache 2.4.10 (and up): https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/apache2 (ppa:ondrej/apache2)
- MySQL 5.6.20 (and up): https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/mysql-5.6 (ppa:ondrej/mysql-5.6)

The process of adding PPA's is easy. Find the "ppa:" line in the list above, open up a terminal, and type:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:name
```

This will add that PPA to your repositories, and you can then run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

to have your packages updated and upgraded just as if it was from the official repositories.

Comment: :Thanks for your help. I've only one doubt in my mind. After running all the above command to upgrade the softwares will there be any damage to my current project files present in www folder or the data present in MySQL database? I don't want to make any kind of damage to these things.

Comment: Upgrading these packages via the PPA repositories will be like upgrading software via the regular repositories. It should not touch your current data.

However, your current data (such as PHP applications and similar) may be incompatible with newer software versions, such as PHP 5.5.